# Type error: Cannot find module '!raw-loader!@types/lodash/common/array.d.ts' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I am getting typescript error when I am building an **NEXT JS** app
Type error: Cannot find module '!raw-loader!@types/lodash/common/array.d.ts'

here is my tsConfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "target": "es2015",
    //"downlevelIteration": true
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "types": ["raw-loader.d.ts", "node"],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "out/types/**/*.ts",
    "build/types/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Here is my raw-loader.d.ts file

```
declare module 'raw-loader!*' {
  const contents: string
  export default contents
}
```

**I am not using webpack.config.js file**

I am using 1 package **@monaco-editor/react**
Here is my component code -

```
'use client';
import Editor, { useMonaco } from '@monaco-editor/react';
import LODASH_array from '!raw-loader!@types/lodash/common/array.d.ts';
import LODASH_common from '!raw-loader!@types/lodash/common/common.d.ts';
import MOMENT from '!raw-loader!moment/moment.d.ts';

export default MyComponent() {
  const monaco = useMonaco();

  useEffect()( => {  
    monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(
        LODASH_array,
        '@types/lodash/common/array.d.ts'
      );
 
    // Moment;
      monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(
        MOMENT.replace('export = moment;', '//export = moment;'),
        'moment/moment.d.ts'
    // Configure source Json and other data sources.
      let libSource = '';

      dataSources.forEach((ds: any) => {
        libSource =
          libSource +
          `\n
                const ${ds.name} = ${JSON.stringify(ds.data, null, 2)};
            `;
      });

      const libUri: any = monaco.Uri.parse('ts:filename/facts.d.ts');
      monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(
        libSource,
        libUri
      );
      monaco.editor.createModel(
        libSource,
        'typescript',
        monaco.Uri.parse(libUri)
      );
    }, [monaco]);

 return <AnotherComponent ..... />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So in **raw-loader.d.ts** file changed line

```
declare module 'raw-loader!*' {
```

to

```
declare module '!raw-loader!*' {
```

this resolved my issue